# Need to convert .ico files to .png with Ruby — any hidden Gems I'm not seeing in Google?

Tags: ruby, png, favicon

We currently have a PHP script doing this, but it fails constantly, so I'm looking for a solution in Ruby.  Basically we are collecting favicons and need to convert any that are in the .ico format into a .png format.

*Please* do not provide links to any hosted services to do this... we've probably already tried them all and abandoned them (this includes Google and Yahoo) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-readimage.php) or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.readimage.php), both available as PHP modules (and very similar); in Ruby use the [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) interface.

Comment: That's great, thanks, I'll give RMagick a go.  I wonder why these image manipulation libraries seem to all be antiquated and unloved... this hasn't had much love since 2009 by the look of it and was recently handed over to another developer.  I'd have thought, Ruby devs being the cool hipster types :P that there'd be some awesome, actively developed gems for doing cool stuff with images.

Comment: @d11wtq: I can't speak for the Ruby bindings, but the actual Image/GraphicsMagick suites are very fine pieces of software with good documentation and maintenance. Do post if you manage to use RMagick; I think a simple conversion (or perhaps "load" plus "write") should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Neither graphicsmagick, nor imagemagick could deal with the .ico file I had (one hangs indefinitely, the other just says it's corrupt).  The "devil" gem, which uses libdevil got me up and running, though again, this seems to be abandoned.  We're using it anyway.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it is really the correct answer, even if I actually used something else!

Comment: @d11wtq: That's very kind! I do actually remember now that ICO files were sort of an issue with both those programs, and I had struggled with this before... with luck, this format will be supported in a future version, though. Anyway, out of curiosity, how *did* you end up manipulating the icons?

Comment: With devil it was easy: https://gist.github.com/1071993.  I briefly started looking at the possibility of extracting another language's graphics handling into a Ruby extension (exploring Qt's C++ code). Unlikely I'll pursue it though.  It feels like there should be something for really simple drawing and stuff.  Proper API, not just a wrapper around a command line tool.

Comment: @d11wtq: Ahh, this Devil library really looks very nice. Good stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [one of the Ruby interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#ruby) to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).